# Debian apache2 overflow

Tags: linux, apache2, debian

I have problem with my Debian server (Linux 2.6.32-5-686 i686) when I start apache2 everything seems ok but in a while apache executable start duplicating it self again and again to thew critical moment when server fall down. I don't know where is the problem. I'm getting lot of these messages in access.log

> ::1 - - [04/Aug/2013:10:16:45 +0200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 136 "-" "Apache (internal dummy connection)"

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the apache wiki regarding this dummy connections http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/InternalDummyConnection

Please revise your settings for *MinSpareServers* and *MaxSpareServers*.